# Floating point number decimal point approximation in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

In my Delphi XE2 Project I am using some real variables to calculate some voucher related data. I have written the following code :

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.Math;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Edit4: TEdit;
    Edit5: TEdit;
    Edit6: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    Label5: TLabel;
    Label6: TLabel;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ServiceTax, RetailPrice, ProcessingFee, VoucherValue, AccountBalance, Airtimepercentage : real;
begin
  RetailPrice := StrToFloatDef(Edit1.text, 0);
  ServiceTax := StrToFloatDef(Edit2.text, 0);
  if (RetailPrice*(10/100) <= 5) then ProcessingFee := RetailPrice*(10/100) else ProcessingFee := 5;
  VoucherValue := (RetailPrice/(1+(ServiceTax/100)) - ProcessingFee);
  AccountBalance := StrToFloatDef(Edit5.text, 0);
  AirTimePercentage := (AccountBalance/VoucherValue)*100;
  Edit3.Text := FloatToStrF(ProcessingFee, ffFixed, 16, 6);
  Edit4.Text := FloatToStrF(VoucherValue, ffFixed, 16, 6);
  Edit6.Text := FloatToStrF(AirTimePercentage, ffFixed, 16, 6);
end;

end.
```

But the problem is that `VoucherValue` is a floating point number. It contains a very long decimal point but my requirement is up to two decimal point only or may be a long decimal point but after two decimal point (example 12.19) all digits will be zero (example 12.190000). So I have tried `FormatFloat` as follows:

```
  VoucherValue := StrToFloatDef(FormatFloat('0.##', FloatToStrF((RetailPrice/(1+(ServiceTax/100)) - ProcessingFee), ffFixed, 16, 6)), 0);
```

But I am unable to compile and getting error as follows:

**`[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(46): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'FormatFloat' that can be called with these arguments`**

And another disadvantage of `FormatFloat` is that it can truncate (i.e. 12.129999 to 12.12) but can't approximate (i.e. 12.129999 to 12.13) but I need the approximation.

Another solution is to use another string variable but I don't like use.

Please suggest me.

Comment: Another day, another guy who needs to read this: WECSSKAFP (Goldberg,1991)
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: you cannot use a floating point type for money. use currency instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the real issue is that your value is not representable, an issue that has been discussed so many times. Your value cannot be exactly represented using binary floating point.

You have two main options:

- Leave the type and value as is, but format to two decimal places on output. For instance `Format('%.2f', [Value])` or `FormatFloat('0.##', Value)`. Contrary to what you state in the question, `FormatFloat` does round to nearest.
- Use a decimal data type and so represent the value exactly.

Answer (score 4):

When the compiler tells you that there's no overload that accepts the arguments you've given it, the first thing you should do is check what overloads are available. Then you'll see that all overloads of `FormatFloat` expect the second parameter to have type `Extended`. You're passing the result of `FloatToStrF`, which returns a string. (Besides, when you call `FloatToStrF`, you ask for six decimal places, so it should be no surprise that you don't get a value rounded to just two.)

Don't convert your value to a string before formatting it; that's what `FormatFloat` will do already.

```
VoucherValue := StrToFloatDef(FormatFloat('0.##', (RetailPrice/(1+(ServiceTax/100)) - ProcessingFee)), 0);
```

Better yet, don't convert your value to a string at all, if a string isn't really what you're after. You evidently still want a numeric value *rounded* to a certain amount, so call `RoundTo` on it. For two decimal places, the second parameter should be −2.

```
VoucherValue := RoundTo(RetailPrice/(1+(ServiceTax/100)) - ProcessingFee, -2);
```

Comment: Better yet, write some simpler sub-expressions instead of seeing how much you can cram into one line.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that RoundTo will round to the nearest representable value